# Convergence of the Power Method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a vector $x^{(0)}$ with $\left\|x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}=1$, I wish to show that the power method :
$$
x^{(k)}=\frac{A x^{(k-1)}}{\left\|A x^{(k-1)}\right\|_{2}}, \quad \mu^{(k)}=\left(x^{(k)}\right)^{T} A x^{(k)}
$$
generates the pair $\left(x^{(k)}, \mu^{(k)}\right)$ such that $\displaystyle x^{(k)}=\frac{A^{k} x^{(0)}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}$ for any matrix $A$.

My attempt by induction:

**Base Case**: For $k=1, \displaystyle x^{(1)}=\frac{A x^{(0)}}{\left\|A x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}$ by definition.

For the inductive step, it seems trivial but I can't seem to figure it out, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Note]** : *The inductive step is indeed trivial, now assume that $\displaystyle x^{(k)}=\frac{A^{k} x^{(0)}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}$ all you have to do is work things out simply by substituting $x^{(k)}$* in $x^{(k+1)}$ due to its recursive nature as you can see :
$$
x^{(k+1)}=\frac{A x^{(k)}}{\left\|A x^{(k)}\right\|_{2}}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{A^{k+1} x^{(0)}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\left\|A^{k+1} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}}=\frac{A^{k+1} x^{(0)}}{\left\|A^{k+1} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}
$$
Since $\displaystyle A x^{(k)}=A \frac{A^{k} x^{(0)}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}=\frac{A^{k+1} x^{(0)}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}$ and $\displaystyle\left\|A x^{(k)}\right\|_{2}=\frac{\left\|A^{k+1} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}}{\left\|A^{k} x^{(0)}\right\|_{2}} .$